# How to use collapse in correct way

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
      <div class="card-header-title" style="border-radius:0px;cursor:pointer;" id="headingOne">
        <i class="pe-7s-angle-up-circle" style="color:#3d68e0;font-size:16px;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne"></i>
        <font data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne">Header</font>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        &nbsp;123
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
      <div class="card-header-title" style="border-radius:0px;cursor:pointer;" id="headingTwo">
        <i class="pe-7s-angle-up-circle" style="color:#3d68e0;font-size:16px;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo"></i>
        <font data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo">Detail</font>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        &nbsp;123
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
      <div class="card-header-title" style="border-radius:0px;cursor:pointer;" id="headingThree">
        <i class="pe-7s-angle-up-circle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree"></i>
        <font data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree">Vendor Price Detail</font>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        &nbsp;123
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
      <div class="card-header-title" style="border-radius:0px;cursor:pointer;" id="headingFour">
        <i class="pe-7s-angle-up-circle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseFour"></i>
        <font data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree">Debtor Price Detail</font>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseFour" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        &nbsp;123
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br />
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
      <div class="card-header-title" style="border-radius:0px;cursor:pointer;" id="headingFive">
        <i class="pe-7s-angle-up-circle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseFive"></i>
        <font data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree">Tesco</font>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseFive" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingFive" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        &nbsp;123
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The Code i Copy from link: https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=bootstrap&file=accordion

I just change the button to font

My Problem is:

The code should be toggle but I click 1 more time to close the card body (not working). Only press other collapse then its close.

How to solve this.

Comment: I fixed your snippet (html in the html box) and it works as described.  What exactly is the problem you're having?  Edit: ok, the first 3 work as described the other two are wrong.

Comment: Predictably: `data-target="#collapseThree"` on 4 and 5

Comment: @freedomn-n my problem like this... when i open page-> collapseOne will be show , this one is ok no problem ... but i press one more time for collapseOne (<font data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsOne">Detail</font>) and its should be close BUT my result is nothing happen....

Comment: @freedomn-n only i press other collapse , the collapseOne will come.. i wan collapseOne can close itself.

Comment: It's doing that for me in your snippet - opens with "Header 1" expanded, click on "header 1" and it collapses, click again, expands, etc.  You need to click on the text, not the div even though you've put cursor-pointer on the div

Comment: Just adding `cursor:pointer` doesn't make it work, that just changes how the cursor looks.

Comment: @freedomn-m so weird ... in my asp.net mvc view not working....

Comment: Did you try it in the updated snippet?   Do you have any other events/js on any of your accordion?  This is why we ask for a [mcve] - showing "working" code doesn't help find the problem.

Comment: @freedomn-m i will check it ... thx

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are facing is because `<font>` have display CSS attribute value inline by default, I would suggest to not using it since its [obsolete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font), to fix the issue I replaced `<font>` tag with `<div>`

**Note**: I also fixed the the collapse attribute for the some of the accordion elements and moved the inline CSS to CSS classes.

```css
.card-header-title {
border-radius:0px;
cursor:pointer;
}
.pe-7s-angle-up-circle {
  color:#3d68e0;
  font-size:16px
}
font {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
      <div class="card-header-title" id="headingOne">
        <i class="pe-7s-angle-up-circle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne"></i>
        <div data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne">Header</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        &nbsp;123
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
      <div class="card-header-title" id="headingTwo">
        <i class="pe-7s-angle-up-circle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo"></i>
        <div data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo">Detail</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        &nbsp;123
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
      <div class="card-header-title" id="headingThree">
        <i class="pe-7s-angle-up-circle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree"></i>
        <div data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree">Vendor Price Detail</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        &nbsp;123
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
      <div class="card-header-title" id="headingFour">
        <i class="pe-7s-angle-up-circle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseFour"></i>
        <div data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseFour">Debtor Price Detail</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseFour" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        &nbsp;123
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br />
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
      <div class="card-header-title" id="headingFive">
        <i class="pe-7s-angle-up-circle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseFive"></i>
        <div data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseFive">Tesco</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseFive" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingFive" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        &nbsp;123
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```